# How to pass message with "post_change_redirect" in Django?

Tags: django, forms

I'm learning about built-in views and forms. In the password_change view from django.contrib.auth.views the parameter "post_change_redirect" is accepted. I want the user to stay on the same settings page, where he changed the password in the first place. But I also want to notify the user that a change was made. So how can I track the confirmation in the template ? Do I have to override the password_change view to pass a message or is there something built in ?

I tried:

```
{% for message in messages %}
  {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
```

But that seems to be empty. Are there any things I can check for ?

The only idea I have so far, is to add another parameter to the post_change_redirect url to track the success. But I don't really like that, because I want the user to stay on the same settings-page.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: no, not really. it looks like there is no message. the question is, if there is anything else built in to verify the successfull change or if i have to modify the view. 
but still thank you for the reply !

Comment: @JasonTS, the "built in" method is a success view.. :)

Comment: @YujiTomita : how can i plug in a view while keeping the same url ? in the documentation i can't find anything else than 'post_change_redirect' which will accept an url.

Comment: @JasonTS, what? You can post_change_redirect='' if you want to load the same page. OTherwise, no, by definition you can not have the same view at the same url.

Comment: @YujiTomita : Right! That's what I'm doing. But when I land on the same page again (due to post_change_redirect). Who I can I tell the User, that it was successfull ? Is there any variable I can read, which tells me, that the user had a successfull change instead of just coming the first time to this page.